# how to return from void inbuilt methods in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to return value from the inbuilt void method. How can I do so?

code

```
 public static boolean upload(DatabaseReference reference, String path, String userUid, String value)
    {

        reference.child(path).setValue(value).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                return true;
            }
        })

        return false;
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot return a value from a method with void result type
```

Edit:

Actually, the code that I am currently using which is not readable at all I know is

```
  DatabaseReference reference = mDatabase.getReference().child(FirebaseVar.USERS).child(mUser.getUid());

                        reference.child(FirebaseVar.NAME).setValue(binding.nameSignUp.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                reference.child(FirebaseVar.ROLE).setValue(selectedRoles).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        reference.child(FirebaseVar.BRANCH).setValue(selectedBranch).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                                reference.child(FirebaseVar.HOSTEL).setValue(selectedHostels).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                                        reference.child(FirebaseVar.GENDER).setValue(checkedbutton.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(SignUpDetailActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

SO my question is how to improve my given code?

Comment: Firebase database operations are asyncronous and return immediately.  The listener you provide won't be invoked until some time later, after your `upload` method has already returned.  You can't make the listener return a value from the enclosing `upload` function.

Comment: You’ll have to use a callback for this.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes Doug so actually my problem is I want to set many values in my firebase database and after all, the values are successfully uploaded then I want to show a message that says "successfully uploaded" so with the help of addOnSuccesListner i can only check one value either set or not but how can I check simultaneously wether all values successfully uploaded or not?

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the one you posted.  Maybe you would like to edit the question to better explain what you're trying to accomplish and where you are stuck implementing that.

Comment: @DougStevenson I posted both the questions.

Comment: I also think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help. Isn't about adding data, but reading, but I think you'll get the idea, as both operations are asynchronous.